# How does the adverbial "limite" differ in meaning from simply saying "presque"?

Tags: sens, usage

> Donc voilà, après le clash entre Taylor Swift et Miley Cyrus, en voilà un autre ! Mais miss Hathaway n’a pas du tout apprécié de se faire **limite** traiter de peste et ne compte pas se laisser faire.

I assume that the adverbial "limite" denotes something more than "presque" does, but not sure exactly what.

Answer (score 2):

The main and possibly only difference is language registry.

*Presque* is standard French.

*Limite* is normally a substantive that started to be used as an adjective and here is colloquially used as an adverb.

As Stéphane commented, *limite* can be considered stronger than *presque*, i.e. closer to the limit, precisely.

In addition to *à deux doigts*, I would also suggest *quasiment* and *pratiquement*.

Comment: Pour le sens, "être à deux doigts de” est peut-être un peu plus proche de “limite” que “presque”. Je pense que ça passe mieux dans la phrase donnée en exemple. L'interprétation “c'est comme si” me vient aussi à l'esprit mais je ne vois aucun moyen de l'insérer dans la phrase sans enfreindre la grammaire d'une autre façon.